# Android studio build and run App with over limit GC size for methods

Tags: android, android-studio, garbage-collection

I got below things in logcat when running my application, I stuck with this and not able to solve this issue any more, I Google it but and for supporting more than 65k method use Android studio I do it but unfortunately can help that too.

Error

```
04-16 18:07:28.442  29389-29389/com.skd.buzzapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 3181 (com_facebook_loginview_text_color) in Lcom/facebook/android/R$color;
04-16 18:07:28.442  29389-29389/com.skd.buzzapp D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0025
04-16 18:07:28.452  29389-29389/com.skd.buzzapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 3265 (com_facebook_login_view) in Lcom/facebook/android/R$styleable;
04-16 18:07:28.452  29389-29389/com.skd.buzzapp D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0005
04-16 18:07:28.452  29389-29389/com.skd.buzzapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 3248 (com_facebook_loginview_log_out_button) in Lcom/facebook/android/R$string;
04-16 18:07:28.452  29389-29389/com.skd.buzzapp D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x001a
04-16 18:07:28.452  29389-29389/com.skd.buzzapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 3246 (com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button) in Lcom/facebook/android/R$string;
04-16 18:07:28.452  29389-29389/com.skd.buzzapp D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x002f
04-16 18:07:28.452  29389-29389/com.skd.buzzapp I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0c76 at 0x32 in Lcom/facebook/widget/LoginButton;.<init>
04-16 18:07:28.452  29389-29389/com.skd.buzzapp I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0c6c at 0x4a in Lcom/facebook/widget/LoginButton;.<init>
04-16 18:07:28.462  29389-29389/com.skd.buzzapp I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0c7c at 0x64 in Lcom/facebook/widget/LoginButton;.<init>
04-16 18:07:28.462  29389-29389/com.skd.buzzapp I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0c7e at 0x69 in Lcom/facebook/widget/LoginButton;.<init>
04-16 18:07:28.462  29389-29389/com.skd.buzzapp I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0c71 at 0x72 in Lcom/facebook/widget/LoginButton;.<init>
04-16 18:07:28.462  29389-29389/com.skd.buzzapp I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0c73 at 0x7f in Lcom/facebook/widget/LoginButton;.<init>
04-16 18:07:28.462  29389-29389/com.skd.buzzapp I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0c75 at 0x89 in Lcom/facebook/widget/LoginButton;.<init>
04-16 18:07:28.462  29389-29389/com.skd.buzzapp I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0c74 at 0x93 in Lcom/facebook/widget/LoginButton;.<init>
04-16 18:07:28.462  29389-29389/com.skd.buzzapp I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0c72 at 0x9d in Lcom/facebook/widget/LoginButton;.<init>
04-16 18:07:28.462  29389-29389/com.skd.buzzapp I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0cc2 at 0x0b in Lcom/facebook/widget/LoginButton;.parseAttributes
04-16 18:07:28.472  29389-29389/com.skd.buzzapp I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0cc3 at 0x13 in Lcom/facebook/widget/LoginButton;.parseAttributes
04-16 18:07:28.472  29389-29389/com.skd.buzzapp I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0cc4 at 0x1b in Lcom/facebook/widget/LoginButton;.parseAttributes
04-16 18:07:28.472  29389-29389/com.skd.buzzapp I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0cc5 at 0x23 in Lcom/facebook/widget/LoginButton;.parseAttributes
```

Answer (score 0):

To build apps with more than 65k methods you must add multi dex support.
Add these to your app gradle file.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14 // Multi Dex not supported below 14
    targetSdkVersion 23

    multiDexEnabled true // To Enable Multi Dex
}

dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false /*Include these three statements to build app quickly (at least faster than     before :p) */
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"  // To avoid GC Limit Exception
    jumboMode = true  // To avoid GC Limit Exception
}

}

dependencies {

compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    /* MultiDex - method count exceeds 65k */
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Now make an Application Singleton Class and Override `attachBaseContext()`

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Don't forget to declare it in your Manifest

```
<application
    android:name=".AppController" <!-- Your Application Singleton Class Name -->
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    ...
    ...
    </application>
```

Due to memory limitations in android studio you still might get GC Error.
Try cleaning you project and then building it again.

You're all set now!